# How do i use TextInput inside a Callout in react-native-maps by airbnb?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to take input from the user in a callout so i can perform actions on it. But using TextInput in MapView.Callout is of no use as the whole Callout is being pressed. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically set the focus to the `TextInput` when the callback of the callout gets called. Give the `TextInput` inside your callout a `ref`

like so `<TextInput ref={textInput => this.textInput = textInput} />`.

Now, inside the callback of the callout simply write.
`this.textInput.focus()`.

**Sidenote:** Make sure you bind to the callback of the callout to `this` or call it inside a fat arrow function so the `this` in `this.textInput.focus()` does not come out to be undefined.
This is a cleaner solution where you do not have to mess around with absolute styles and component overlapping.